# Is it easy or even possible yet to manage windows firewall with powershell?

Tags: powershell, windows, wmi, windows-server-2012, windows-firewall

I'm doing some POC testing on a server 2012 environment, and during initial firewall configuration I find myself going to the GUI repeatedly when I'd really much rather be able to write a script. I've searched around but I can't find anything about new powershell commands in 3.0 nor anything via WMI.

Is there anything I'm missing or is this still largely a GUI-oriented task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible...

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831755.aspx

Do a:

```
Get-Command *-*firewall*
```

to see various commands available as well.

Comment: Looks like this is what I was hoping to find! I'm surprised this didn't come up with even a basic search. Thanks!